# Odds Ratio or 2 Prop Z Test

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, biostatistics, odds-ratio, ab-test

We would like to conduct an AB Test between 2 groups of people and the apps that people have to see which ones over or underindex.
Which is more appropriate odds ratio or 2 proportional z test and why?

However my concern with the odds ratio is that it would be alot harder to explain odds to a stakeholder than it would be for regular probability.

**Raw Data**

| DeviceId | App | Audience Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tinder | A |
| 1 | Bumble | A |
| 1 | CNN | A |
| 2 | Tinder | A |
| 2 | Bumble | A |
| 2 | Solitaire | A |
| 3 | Tinder | B |
| 3 | Bumble | B |
| 3 | Disney+ | B |
| 4 | Disney+ | B |
| 4 | Tinder | B |
| 5 | WSJ | A |
| 5 | Disney+ | A |
| 6 | WSJ | B |
| 6 | Solitaire | B |
| 6 | CNN | B |

Aggregated you get the below:
**Group A Aggregated Statistics**

| Apps | Total Devices | Percentage | 1-Percentage | Odds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tinder | 2 | 67% | 33% | 2.02 |
| Bumble | 2 | 67% | 33% | 2.02 |
| Solitaire | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |
| CNN | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |
| Disney+ | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |
| WSJ | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |

**Group B Aggregated Statistics**

| Counts for Apps | Total Devices | Percentage | 1-Percentage | Odds Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tinder | 2 | 67% | 33% | 2.02 |
| Bumble | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |
| Solitaire | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |
| CNN | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |
| Disney+ | 2 | 67% | 33% | 2.02 |
| WSJ | 1 | 33% | 67% | 0.49 |

Odds Ratio vs Probability Comparison

| App | Group A Probability | Group A 1-Probability | Group B Probability | Group B 1 - Probability | P1/P2 | Odds Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tinder | 67% | 33% | 67% | 33% | 1 | 100% |
| Bumble | 67% | 33% | 33% | 67% | 2 | 400% |
| Solitaire | 33% | 67% | 33% | 67% | 1 | 100% |
| CNN | 33% | 67% | 33% | 67% | 1 | 100% |
| Disney+ | 33% | 67% | 67% | 33% | 0.5 | 25% |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [usual test](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/9/9.4) of the difference between two proportions. You'll need to do it separately for each of the 6 apps. Be mindful of the fact that you're conducting multiple tests; to control the overall Type I error probability, you might consider using a [Bonferroni correction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BonferroniCorrection.html).

If you are creating confidence intervals for the differences in probabilities, I suggest using the [Agresti-Caffo](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DescTools/html/BinomDiffCI.html) method.

Comment: Agree (heart) on the bonferoni correction and the multiple comparison bias. Good call. That has been a back burner thought for a while.